# Remove Last Comma and CsvHelper Appending First Line To Header

Tags: c#, list, export-to-csv, csvhelper

How can I stop CsvHelper adding a comma the end of the line and CsvHelper is appending the first Data line to the header.

I have looked at all the configuration options in CsvHelper but cannot find anything to stop the comma from appending to the end of the line. Looked also to see if there is away to output the first data line under the headers.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(csvLocation, csvFileName)))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                csvWriter.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                csvWriter.Configuration.AutoMap<SancationsManagement.SancationsCSV>();


                csvWriter.WriteHeader<SancationsManagement.SancationsCSV>();
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(sancationsList);

                writer.Flush();


            }
```

This is how the output looks:

```
FormNumber,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,YearOfBirth,Address,City,PostCode,Country,Nationality,U010000057067603239068628483086,O,Mokrousova,,,,,,UKRAINE,
0129700010019711236864477,S,Sungeor,,,,,,AUSTRALIA,
0129700010019451234636200,D,Alroe,,,,,,AUSTRALIA,
U010000057067603239067627525996,Y,Furusawa,,,,,,JAPAN,
U010000057067603239060621550490,C,Tempany-Afdhal,,,,,,UNITED STATES,
0129400010029651236364094,S,Ali,,,,,,BAHRAIN,
A034504341167909899070630095197,H,Palilh,,,,,,COLOMBIA,
```

Would like it to look like:

```
FormNumber,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,YearOfBirth,Address,City,PostCode,Country,Nationality
U010000057067603239068628483086,O,Mokrousova,,,,,,UKRAINE
0129700010019711236864477,S,Sungeor,,,,,,AUSTRALIA
0129700010019451234636200,D,Alroe,,,,,,AUSTRALIA
U010000057067603239067627525996,Y,Furusawa,,,,,,JAPAN
U010000057067603239060621550490,C,Tempany-Afdhal,,,,,,UNITED STATES
0129400010029651236364094,S,Ali,,,,,,BAHRAIN
A034504341167909899070630095197,H,Palilh,,,,,,COLOMBIA
```

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly the value for Nationality seems blank. If you don't want all attributes being written to the csv file. You should write fields instead of the record.

```
csvWriter.WriteField("field1");
// ...
csvWriter.WriteField("fieldn");
csvWriter.NextRecord();
```